# Stylegan3: RuntimeError: The size of tensor a (24) must match the size of tensor b (12) at non-singleton dimension 0

Tags: python, pytorch, nvidia, generative-adversarial-network, stylegan

I am trying to train stylegan3 with my custom images. The dataset contains image with resolution 256*256, and I am using this command to train the model:

```
python train.py --outdir=~/training-runs --cfg=stylegan3-r --data=dataset/custom_dataset.zip     --gpus=1 --batch=32 --gamma=0.5 --mirror=1 --kimg=1000 --snap=10     --resume=https://api.ngc.nvidia.com/v2/models/nvidia/research/stylegan3/versions/1/files/stylegan3-t-ffhqu-256x256.pkl
```

The error I am getting is

Traceback (most recent call last):

```
File "train.py", line 286, in <module>
  main() # pylint: disable=no-value-for-parameter
  File "/opt/conda/envs/stylegan3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/click/core.py", line 1128, in __call__
    return self.main(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/conda/envs/stylegan3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/click/core.py", line 1053, in main
    rv = self.invoke(ctx)
  File "/opt/conda/envs/stylegan3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/click/core.py", line 1395, in invoke
    return ctx.invoke(self.callback, **ctx.params)
  File "/opt/conda/envs/stylegan3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/click/core.py", line 754, in invoke
    return __callback(*args, **kwargs)
  File "train.py", line 281, in main
    launch_training(c=c, desc=desc, outdir=opts.outdir, dry_run=opts.dry_run)
  File "train.py", line 96, in launch_training
    subprocess_fn(rank=0, c=c, temp_dir=temp_dir)
  File "train.py", line 47, in subprocess_fn
    training_loop.training_loop(rank=rank, **c)
  File "/home/jovyan/stylegan3/stylegan3/training/training_loop.py", line 162, in training_loop
    misc.copy_params_and_buffers(resume_data[name], module, require_all=False)
  File "/home/jovyan/stylegan3/stylegan3/torch_utils/misc.py", line 162, in copy_params_and_buffers
    tensor.copy_(src_tensors[name].detach()).requires_grad_(tensor.requires_grad)
RuntimeError: The size of tensor a (24) must match the size of tensor b (12) at non-singleton dimension 0
```

I tried changing the resolution a couple of times but that did not work